# MonetDB - COPY into file including column names as first row

Tags: monetdb

What I'm trying to accomplish is dump query results into CSV file but also include column names as a first row. I tried using `COPY SELECT 'name1', 'name2' UNION SELECT column1, column2 FROM ...` and this works in situations it is a simple query. I need to perform `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` operations but these will apply to whole result set and not just the second `SELECT` statement resulting in errors, e.g. `SELECT: no such column 'column2'`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary table like

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... WITH DATA;`

and then apply the union trick to get the column names into the file. But generally, adding column names to CSV output is not supported.